# Finding the change in radius that induces an $11\%$ drop in gravitational force between two bodies.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, mathematical-physics

How come differentials only estimate the answer and don't give an exact answer that you might get when you calculate the real figure using other methods?

Example: Let $F = Gm_1m_2/r^2$

Let $r=8$. What is the change in $r$ that would correspond to an 11% decrease in $F$?

My calculations is that $r$ changes by .44 but this isn't what I get when I calculate this by hand.

Comment: They *don't* only estimate the answer, in my experience, which leads me to believe that you're talking about something specific that you haven't told us. Please [edit] your question to include such relevant details. Perhaps an example to illustrate what you're talking about?

Comment: Let me guess. You computed $F(r+\Delta r) \approx -2(Gm_1m_2/r^3)\Delta r = -\frac{2\Delta r}{r}F(r)$, and solved $\frac{2\Delta r}{r} = 0.11$. Yes, the differential only gives an approximation, it is a _good_ approximation when the change is small, but for a change of this magnitude, it's only so-so. You get a better approximation if you take the derivative at an intermediate point, but that complicates the computation.

Comment: Because in general, derivatives aren't constant. The change of a value is the integral of the derivative. If you approximate the integral by $f'(r_0)\cdot\Delta r$, you have an error (that may be $0$). The larger $\Delta r$ is, the more space the derivative has to change, the less accurate (in general) the approximation becomes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\rho$ be the new radius. Then you want to have $$0.89=\cfrac{\left(\cfrac{Gm_1m_2}{\rho^2}\right)}{\left(\cfrac{Gm_1m_2}{8^2}\right)}=\frac{64}{\rho^2},$$ so $$\rho^2=\frac{64}{0.89},$$ and so $\rho=\sqrt{\dfrac{64}{0.89}}.$ The difference, then, is $\sqrt{\dfrac{64}{0.89}}-8.$ An approximate answer is $0.48.$ I'm not sure what happened in your calculations, but you must have made a mistake somewhere.

---

Now I understand what you did. The principle behind differential approximation is that $$\Delta f\approx\frac{df}{dx}\cdot\Delta x,$$ and that this approximation can be made as close as we like, simply by making $\Delta x$ small enough. The problem is that "small enough" will vary from function to function. Here, you were able to get an approximation within about $0.04,$ which isn't bad, but to get a better approximation to $\Delta F$, we'd want a less substantial $\Delta r$